# Проверка на null

Tags: javascript

Функция должна возвращать true, если в строке одинаковое кол-во символов 'o' и 'x', но если передать функции строку 'xxxm', вызывается ошибка 'Cannot read property 'length' of null', вроде и проверка есть(в закомментированом варианте), но даже так вызывается ошибка, возможно проверка неправильная?

```
function XO(str) {
    console.log(str);

    // if( str.length === 0 || ( str !== null && (str.match(/o/gi).length !== null && str.match(/x/gi).length !== null) ) && (str.match(/o/gi).length === str.match(/x/gi).length) ){
    //   return true;
    // }else{
    //   return false;
    // }

    return ( str.length == 0 || (str.match(/o/gi).length === str.match(/x/gi).length) ) ? true : false;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match()` возвращает либо НЕпустой массив совпадений, либо null;

Можно использовать логическое ИЛИ `||`: null в логическом контексте будет false, поэтому возьмется пустой массив справа.

```js
console.log( x_o_areEqual( "xoxoxo" ) );
console.log( x_o_areEqual( "xxxm" ) );
console.log( x_o_areEqual( "xxxoo" ) );

function x_o_areEqual(str) {
  let o = str.match(/o/gi) || [];
  let x = str.match(/x/gi) || [];

  return o.length === x.length;
}
```

Можно использовать и в виде `let o_len = ( str.match(/o/gi) || [] ).length;`

Comment: Выполнение кода прямо на сайте есть только для JS?

Comment: @Стас Только JS...

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно: если совпадений с регулярным выражением нет, то возвращается null, а не пустой массив

```js
function XO(str) {
  const matchO = str.match(/o/gi);
  const matchX = str.match(/x/gi);
  
  return (
    matchO !== null &&
    matchX !== null &&
    matchO.length === matchX.length
  );
  
  // Такой же результат
  // return (
  //  matchO &&
  //  matchX &&
  //  matchO.length === matchX.length
  //);
}

console.log(XO('xxxm'));
console.log(XO('xoo'));
console.log(XO('xxoo'));
```